# How do I post www-form-urlencoded content-type data and accept json using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

fiddler settings:

Url

http://localhost:8080/lzp/servRoot (post)

Headers

`User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Length: 86
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

RequestBody
`className=com.lzp.service.UserInfoService&methodName=login&user_name=123&user_pwd=123`

And response

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/json;charset=gbk
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{"msg":false}`

It returns `{"msg":false}` using fiddler.

[image]

Here is my code using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("lzp/servRoot", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("className", "com.lzp.service.UserInfoService");
request.AddParameter("methodName", "login");
request.AddParameter("user_name", "123");
request.AddParameter("user_pwd", "123");
var response = client.Execute<TestResultModel>(request);
var res = response.Data;
```

and the `TestResultModel`:

```
public class TestResultModel
{
   public string msg { get; set; }
}
```

Why can't I get deserialize response data?[image]

Comment: Do you have to use RestSharp?

Comment: No, I've changed to use `WebRequest` and solved. Just want to konw if this can be done by restsharp :)

Comment: I won't post this as an answer because it's not what you asked, but [here's how you would do the same with Flurl](https://gist.github.com/tmenier/41c672fab22cd3949e745860c4c23c40#file-flurl-example-cs).